# Fill empty cells with duplicates in a DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table similar to following:

```
    +----------+----+--------------+-------------+
    |      Date|Hour|       Weather|Precipitation|
    +----------+----+--------------+-------------+
    |2013-07-01|   0|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-01|   3|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-01|   6|         clear|trace of p...|
    |2013-07-01|   9|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-01|  12|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-01|  15|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-01|  18|          rain|         null|
    |2013-07-01|  21|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-02|   0|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-02|   3|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-02|   6|          rain|low precip...|
    |2013-07-02|   9|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-02|  12|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-02|  15|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-02|  18|          null|         null|
    |2013-07-02|  21|          null|         null|
    +----------+----+--------------+-------------+
```

The idea is to fill columns `Weather` and `Precipitation` with values at 6 and 18 hours and at 6 hours respectfully. Since this table illustrates a `DataFrame` structure, simple iteration through this seemes to be irrational.
I tried something like this:

```
//_weather stays for the table mentioned
def fillEmptyCells: Unit = {
    val hourIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("Hour")
    val dateIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("Date")
    val weatherIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("Weather")
    val precipitationIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("Precipitation")

    val days = _weather.select("Date").distinct().rdd
    days.foreach(x => {
      val day = _weather.where("Date == $x(0)")
      val dayValues = day.where("Hour == 6").first()
      val weather = dayValues.getString(weatherIndex)
      val precipitation = dayValues.getString(precipitationIndex)
      day.rdd.map(y => (_(0), _(1), weather, precipitation))
    })
  }
```

However, this ugly piece of code seemes to smell because of iterating through an `RDD` instead of handling it in a distributed manner. It also has to form a new `RDD` or `DataFrame` from pieces what can be problematic (I have no idea how to do this). Is there more elegant and simple way to solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can easily create a `timestamp` column by combining `Date` and `Hour`, what I would do next is :

1. convert this `timestamp` (probably in milliseconds or seconds) into an `hourTimestamp` : `.withColumn("hourTimestamp", $"timestamp" // 3600`) ?
2. create 3 columns corresponding to the different possible hour lags (3,6,9)
3. `coalesce` these 3 columns + the original one

Here is the code for `Weather` (do the same for `Precipitation`):

```
val window = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("hourTimestamp")
val weatherUpdate = df
                    .withColumn("WeatherLag1", lag("Weather", 3).over(window))
                    .withColumn("WeatherLag2", lag("Weather", 6).over(window))
                    .withColumn("WeatherLag3", lag("Weather", 9).over(window))
                    .withColumn("Weather",coalesce($"Weather",$"WeatherLag1",$"WeatherLag2",$"WeatherLag3"))
```

Comment: This is amazing! The most elegant implementation I could even imagine! Thank you!