# NullPointerException on DataFrame where

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following method written in Scala:

```
def fillEmptyCells: Unit = {
    val hourIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("Hour")
    val dateIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("Date")
    val groundSurfaceIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("GroundSurface")
    val snowyGroundIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("SnowyGroundSurface")
    val precipitationIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("catPrec")
    val snowDepthIndex = _weather.schema.fieldIndex("catSnowDepth")

    var resultDf : DataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row],_weather.schema)

    val days = _weather.select("Date").distinct().rdd
    _weather.where("Date = '2014-08-01'").show()
    days.foreach(x => {
      println(s"Date = '${x.getDate(0)}'")
      _weather.where(s"Date = '${x.getDate(0)}'").show()
      val day = _weather.where(s"Date = '${x.getDate(0)}'")
      val dayValues = day.where("Hour = 6").first()
      val grSur = dayValues.getString(groundSurfaceIndex)
      val snSur = dayValues.getString(snowyGroundIndex)
      val prec = dayValues.getString(precipitationIndex)
      val snowDepth = dayValues.getString(snowDepthIndex)
      val dayRddMapped = day.rdd.map(y => (y(0), y(1), grSur, snSur, y(4), y(5), y(6), y(7), prec, snowDepth))
        .foreach(z => {
          resultDf = resultDf.union(Seq(z).toDF())
        })
    })
    resultDf.show(20)
    Unit
  }
```

The problem is this line: `_weather.where(s"Date = '${x.getDate(0)}'").show()` where the `NullPointerException` occurs. As can be seen at line above, I print the where clause to console (it looks like `Date = '2014-06-03'`) and the line just before foreach takes one of the outputs as parameters and works fine. `_weather` is a class variable and does not change while this method is running. Debugger shows more stranger things: `_weather` gets `null`ed after first iteration.

What is the source of this magic and how can I avoid it?

Moreover, if you have any suggestions according to architecture and code quality, welcome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122826/fill-empty-cells-with-duplicates-in-a-dataframe)

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.where(Dataset.scala:1344)
    at org.[package].WeatherHelper$$anonfun$fillEmptyCells$1.apply(WeatherHelper.scala:148)
    at org.[package].WeatherHelper$$anonfun$fillEmptyCells$1.apply(WeatherHelper.scala:146)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
19/01/10 13:39:35 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 420)
```

The class name is `WeatherHelper` it's just a part of the whole stacktrace which repeats ~20 times.

Comment: could you edit your question and include the Stacktrace?

Comment: Edited my post and added the stacktrace to the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use dataframes in RDD code (you use dataframes in `days.foreach`), th dataframes are null here as it only lives on the driver, but not on the executors

Comment: I've insvestigated a little and found that you're right. Here is related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715661/spark-how-can-i-create-local-dataframe-in-each-executor